# HighCharts - how to set labels font color for printing?

Tags: printing, highcharts, export

I need to change the chart labels font color for printing.
I tried :

```
exporting: {
                    buttons: {
                        contextButton: {
                            menuItems: [{
                                text: 'Print',
                                onclick: function() {
                                    this.print();
                                }
                            }]
                        }
                    },
                    chartOptions: {
                        yAxis : {
                            labels: {
                                style: {
                                    color: 'black'
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It is known bug, reported to our developers here https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/2022, because we have problem with chartOptions for axis.

Comment: That's actually not the issue (see my comment in the thread you linked). Printing is handled separately from exporting, and it from reading the source it seems chartOptions are not used for printing at all. :(

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Highcharts doesn't seem to consider chartOptions when printing.

A possible workaround is to create a print-only CSS file and make the labels black there. The following would change label colors for both axes. I'm not sure how you could only style y without x.

```
svg g.highcharts-axis-label text {
  fill: #000 !important;
}
```

Put that in a file called print.css, then include it in the `<head>` like so:

```
<link href="print.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" />
```